# Help needed for statistical analysis of pitch class sets

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, music-theory

Within Music Analysis, there is a quite mathematical type of analysis which looks at pitch class sets ($pcs$), not surprisingly known as pitch class set analysis.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory_(music) for more details. As the article points out, "musical set theory is more closely related to group theory and combinatorics than to mathematical set theory".

Pitch Class set analysis is all based around modular arithmetic, $Mod(12)$ (which represents the chromatic octave).  Analysis typically proceeds along the lines of demonstrating that particular $pcs$ are present (or absent) in a piece (or in various sections in a piece) along with related sets, thereby demonstrating an organic unity in the piece.  Such analysis is almost invariably selective.

What I would like to do is to be able to do a comprehensive, statistical analysis of a piece of music, but I'm struggling to come up with the algorithms to generate the comprehensive list of $pcs$ and their frequencies used in a piece.

What is the best way to represent the affinities between individual pitches?  A $pcs$ may be defined as a group of contiguous (or linked) pitches, but it gets complicated.  Note that you can have simultaneous pitches (also known as a chord) or a succession of pitches (also known as a melody), or a combination of the two.  You can also have disjunct pitches which are nevertheless somehow related (e.g. same instrument with a rest in the middle, or similar pitch range, though these seem a bit more "dodgy" or subjective).

Once I have a representation of how all the individual pitches in a piece are related, what is the most efficient way to traverse this data to statistically extract all the $pcs$ present in the piece of music?

I would also like to be able to run the analysis both $Mod(12)$ and $Mod(11)$ and $Mod(13)$.  I have a suspicion that "tonal" pieces which exhibit a preponderance of many 'tonal' $pcs$ (such as [0,1,3], [0,2,4], [0,2,5] and [0,3,7]) "$Mod(12)$" would have a more random collection of $pcs$ under a different modulus;  conversely I would expect that atonal pieces would have similar profiles regardless of modulus.  I would like to be able to confirm or deny this suspicion.

Comment: Unless you're talking about using extremely non-standard scales, why would you do this kind of analysis (mod $11$) or (mod $13$)?  You would then be equating as "pitch classes" notes which differ by other than octaves.  The octave-based notion of pitch classes really isn't arbitrary; it's dictated by Fourier analysis.  (Incidentally, since most normal music won't span $12$ octaves, you will still see structure when you reduce mod $11$ or $13$, but that's just the (mod $12$) structure bleeding through since $11$ and $13$ are so close to $12$.)

Comment: @Tad I'm drawing the distinction between tonal music (by say Haydn) and atonal music (by say Schoenberg).  With tonal music, there is the assumption that you can substitute one octave for another (Eb3 for Eb4 for Eb5 for example) so an Eb chord with any voicing would be [0, 3, 7].  Run the same analysis under mod11 or mod 13 & they wouldn't be, so you can use this to demonstrate that a piece is "tonal".  My suspicion is that if you took a piece assumed to be atonal (e.g. Schoenberg Op. 19 no 6) that results would be more similar, showing that the piece is indeed atonal.  Hope this makes sense!

Comment: @Tad I'm hoping for a proof by contradiction.  PCS theory is mainly used on atonal or quasi-atonal pieces of music (e.g. Bartok string quartet no 3).  The seminal work is Forte: _The_ _Structure_ _of_ _Atonal_ _Music._ Note also that there will be differences in the number of prime forms and what those prime forms are.  For example, [0,4,8] under mod 11 is no longer a prime form - it can be simplified down via [4,8,11] to [0,4,7] and then to [0,3,7].  Conversely [0,3,8] **is** a prime form mod 13, though not mod 12.

Comment: Right. If you work mod m, where m is relatively prime to 12, then the music needs to have a range on the order of 12m notes in order for the (mod 12) effects to spread out evenly (mod m).  So just watch out for that!  (BTW, I disagree about octave substitution distinguishing tonal music from atonal music.  You mention Schoenberg -- that's a great example: serial (12-tone) music generally respects octave substitutions even though it's atonal.)

Comment: @Tad - pcs theory was originally designed to help analyse music that was atonal but **not** serial.  I was careful to choose a Schoenberg piece that predates serialism as my example!  By contrast, Bartok is often considered to be atonal, but one technique he uses is "mistuning", which would show up when analysing pcs Mod 11 (I think).

I'm no fan of pcs theory - my gut feeling is that it only "works" because the people that use it are very selective about the sets which they highlight, hence the desire to do a complete statistical analysis of every single pcs used.